# Grouping a column values using pd.cut - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  a df as shown below

df

```
ID       Age
1        0
2        20
3        50
4        70
5        100
6        150
7        5
```

From the above I would like to score the customer based on age.

Conditions:

```
if Age <= 0, then Score = 100
if 0 < Age <= 10, then Score = 90
if 10 < Age <= 30, then Score = 80
if 30 < Age <= 90, then Score = 50
else Score = 10
```

Expected Output

```
ID       Age           Score      
1        0             100     
2        20            80    
3        50            50
4        70            50
5        100           10
6        150           10
7        5             90
```

Tried below fn:

```
def AgeScoring(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 100
    elif x <= 10 :
        return 90
    elif x <= 30: 
        return 80
    elif x <= 90:
        return 50
    else:
        return 10



df['Score'] = df['Age'].apply(AgeScoring)
```

My question is how it can be done by using pd.cut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the bins and assign the Score as the bin label. Here I explicitly wrote the closure as `right=True`, which is the default.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Score'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=[-np.inf, 0, 10, 30, 90, np.inf], 
                     labels=[100, 90, 80, 50, 10], right=True)

   ID  Age Score
0   1    0   100
1   2   20    80
2   3   50    50
3   4   70    50
4   5  100    10
5   6  150    10
6   7    5    90
```